# Can I put badge inside bootstrap input?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have effect similar to the one below. Of course best KISS, without tons of JS, etc.

Possible? Would be glad to see some working demo. Best for Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.

For now I have tried with append:

```
$ ->
   $('#ajax_search_input').append('#danger")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/sLmyJ/ I forked also this: http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/kvH9E/ regarding adding of icon. Can it be generalized to badge?

[image]

Comment: A requirement is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.  You need to actually attempt something then ask a specific question.

Comment: @Anonymous fiddle included

Comment: The add on is for bootstrap 3.0 though - but if you want that here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MeJYv/ (is that what you're looking to do?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need javascript to accomplish this - you can use absolute positioning to make it appear as if the label is inside of the input. Simple demo below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sLmyJ/1/

```
.label-danger {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Edit - to expand on this, you cannot have any additional elements inside of an `input`. This is one reason why the `button` element is often used instead of `input[type="button"]`.

Comment: I could see there being issues with a long label not leaving enough input room on a small screen, but it's hard to say without knowing your content.